# Запуск gui через скрипты

Tags: debian, kde

Подскажите пожалуйста, программа запускается из командной строки от имени текущего пользователя `./binary` без проблем. Но если перейти в каталог и жмакнуть 2 раза, то появляется окно с предложением запустить его, жмакаем запустить. Но дальше ничего не происходит.

DEBIAN wheeze, KDE 4.

Comment: *ничего не происходит* — а разве что-то должно происходить???

Answer (score 0):

Запускатся гуишный интерфейс конечно, из командной строки то запускается. Впрочем решил проблему через направление ярлыка на скрипт, а из него запуск программы. В скрипте прописал экспорт на библиотеки, почемуто при стандартном user подходе
не подсасывались необходимые библиотеки. Хотя они были прописаны в `ld.so.d` и виделись через `locate`.